# Spliting version number from dependency jar using spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am using **spring-boot-maven-plugin** for creating a fat jar of my project, How can I split version number from the dependency jars getting created inside Boot-Inf/lib. As per my requirement I don't want version to be appended. I tried with maven-dependency-plugin that is working fine, but I need solution with sprint-boot-maven-plugin. Please suggest!!.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the artifact-name with the `maven boot plugin`:

In this case, it will be `NewJarName.jar`

```xml
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>NewJarName</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Adding this configuration will change my final jar name(Fat jar) but i want to remove version from the dependency jar i.e included inside the jar. So it is like jar inside jar.